# SSISをSQL Serverから暗号化したパスワードで使う方法

Tags: sql-server

ローカル環境でSSISパッケージ(.dtsx)を作成した後、別環境のSQL Serverのジョブにパッケージを組み込んで実行するとエラーとなってしまいます。
そこで、dtsxファイルをテキストフォーマットとして開き以下の用に暗号化されたパスワードを平文に書き換えて実行しています。

```
        <DTS:ConnectionManager
      DTS:ConnectionString="Data Source=DB名;User ID=sqluser名;Initial Catalog=DB名;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Auto Translate=false;">
      <DTS:Password
        DTS:Name="Password"
        Sensitive="1"
        Encrypted="0">**暗号化なしのパスワード**</DTS:Password>
    </DTS:ConnectionManager>
```

暗号化したパスワードまたはLOCALHOSTの表記でSSISを実行する方法についてわかりますでしょうか。